# Немогу понять как убрать ошибку зависимости

Tags: json, yii2, yii, composer

Здравствуйте.
После установки пакета и его дальнейшей инстилляции вылезла ошибка:

```
 Problem 1
- Installation request for yiisoft/yii2-composer 2.0.3 -> satisfiable
by yiisoft/yii2-composer[2.0.3].
- yiisoft/yii2-composer 2.0.3 requires composer-plugin-api 1.0.0 -> no
matching package found.
Problem 2
- yiisoft/yii2-composer 2.0.3 requires composer-plugin-api 1.0.0 -> no
matching package found.
- yiisoft/yii2 2.0.3 requires yiisoft/yii2-composer * -> satisfiable by
yiisoft/yii2-composer[2.0.3].
- Installation request for yiisoft/yii2 2.0.3 -> satisfiable by
yiisoft/yii2[2.0.3].
```

Почитал вроде написать пишут что нужно внести изменения в файл composer.json но так я и не понял в какой именно файл и что точно в моем случае нужно тот что лежит в системе по адресу юзернейм\аппдата\роаминг\компосер или тот который лежит в папке юии?
Попробовал тупо поменять в джейсоне версию composer-plugin-api 1.0.0 на стабильную сейчас 1.1.0 но выбивает ошибку конфликта.

Comment: fxp/composer-asset-plugin пробовал разные версии от последней и вниз по нисходящей непомогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю может и тупо сделал: взял 2 файла `composer`'a из корня с последней версии `advanced` и просто скопировал себе в проект поверх своих.